# Principal quantum number of the classical particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

The example 7.9 in [this page](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-3/pages/7-4-the-quantum-particle-in-a-box) shows the principal quantum number of the classical particle.

> A small 0.40-kg cart is moving back and forth along an air track
> between two bumpers located 2.0 m apart. We assume no friction;
> collisions with the bumpers are perfectly elastic so that between the
> bumpers, the car maintains a constant speed of 0.50 m/s. Treating the
> cart as a quantum particle, estimate the value of the principal
> quantum number that corresponds to its classical energy.

In the result, the principal quantum number of the cart is huge due to the high kinetic energy. If the cart moved very very slow, can we find the cart at other place? Why not?

Comment: I was with you until the last sentence.  Can you clarify what you mean at the end?

Comment: I meant, in reality, there is no probability to find the cart at other place, but according to the formula, if the cart moves very slow, the wave mechanism will become more significant. I cannot understand the incompatibility between the formula and the reality.

Comment: Are you imagining a situation like this:  The cart is moving very slowly, but is near the left bumper.  It seems that the probability of finding it near the right bumper is zero.  Is there any probability of finding it near the right bumper?  If that's the question, I'll challenge you with this:  why do you specify that the cart is moving slowly.  What does "slow" mean?  Slow compared to what?

Comment: Maybe slow enough that the quantum mechanics is visible?

Comment: @garyp Maybe ~$4\cdot 10^{-34}$m/s , so it is in the ground state?

Answer (score 1):

In the link you give it says "as though the cart were a quantum particle", so to ask:

> If the cart moved very very slow, can we find the cart at other place

is to ask if the kinetic energy is very very small: "can it behave as a true quantum particle".

In the link they answer using the "[bohr correspondence principle"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bohr-correspondence/).

Considering that the energy is found to be 0.05J , our best timing is nanoseconds, and $h=6.62607015×10^{-34}$ Js the HUP always holds as if h=0, so there is no envelope in which  a probable location can be measured.

The problem makes it clear that the relationships used are for the large energies, where the quantum formalism and the classical one give the same result, for low energy  levels there is no connection between classical and quantum."However we cannot apply classical formalism to a quantum system in a low number quantum state". Your "very low energy" falls in this category. In classical physics there are no "probable states" for simple kinematic problems.

Comment: I cannot understand how to apply the uncertainty principle to this question to explain the speed of the cart cannot be such small.

Comment: when I started to answer I tried it, and have not found a way to do it. Remember the uncertainty principles (there are more than one) are mathematical envelopes of noncommuting operators in QM. That has no analogue in classical dimensions at al. That's why they use the Bohr correspondence  which does not hold for low energies.

Comment: @IvanaGyro   You may solve for the fantastically small speed of the ground state--assuming the nonsensical application of the formulas. The uncertainties are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#Position_and_momentum_probability_distributions). Also look at the next subsection.